# Making a level progression system similar to Bravely Default's

Tags: algorithm, rpg

So I am working on an RPG and I want the level up system to be similar to Bravely Default's, which must be similar to how FF classically levels up characters.

What I know about the level up in the game is that.

1. The game starts of with a large exp pool to fulfill, and the enemies give large drops of exp too (ex: in lvl 1 areas enemies give 50-150 exp points, and you need around 500 exp to reach lvl 2 and so on)
2. The larger the level, the more exp you will need (to the point you need x0 000 exp points to continue in the midgame), however in the late game, the exp point does not increase exponentially (let's say it doesn't reach x00 000 not even at level 99)

Obviously, we want more effort to gain more levels, but this is more about assigning the enemies appropriate exp points depending on the region of the game.

Currently my algorith is lvl = constant * sqrt(exp), however I feel this formula doesn't work for very large numbers.

Edit: so i watched a let's play  of Bravely Default 2, and this is the level up progression i want:

- Level 1 - 72 exp
- Level 10 - 3600 exp
- Level 20 - 6976 exp
- Level 30 - 10268 exp
- Level 40 - 13124 exp
- Level 50 - 15980 exp
- Level 60 - 18836 exp

It's hard to search for further levels caps after level 60, so i hope this data is enough to get how i want the experience needed for levelling up is like: the number of exp increases by a lot in the beginning but it starts to plateau at 20 000 exp in the late levels.
The digits look what i would say "interesting", not a lot zeroes, the numbers look almost random and it's hard to guess the relation of the exp and the level.

Comment: [We have lots of previous Q&A about formulas to map between levels and XP requirements](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=xp+formula) - what have you tried based on your research so far, what specifically do you dislike about the solutions you've tried, and what concretely should an answer do in order to be a good fit for your game?

Comment: honestly, the formula i've been playeing with my calculator lvl = constant * sqrt(exp) and xp = (lvl^2/constant^2) to calculate the experience needed per level. My problem is that i am not finding a good constant that can *hide* well the correlation between the level and the experience needed. What i mean is that when i play i game like Bravely Default, i look at the exp numbers and i say "wow thats a lot of points me like big point go brrr" but with the formula i am seeing lots of zeroes in the first 3-5 digits which is not very good for the fun factor of watching exp increase.

Comment: Want to describe your ideal number of zeroes at each milestone level in your question, so we can use that to grade potential answers?

Comment: so i am watching the numbers per 10 levels on let's plays.

lvl 1 = 72 exp
lvl 10 = 3600 exp
lvl 20 =  6976 exp
lvl 30 = 10268 exp
lvl 40 = 13124 exp
lvl 50 = 15980 exp
lvl 60 = 18836 exp

and i guess with this we can get the gist of it

Comment: Don't tell me in the comments, **edit your question** so that it details your requirements in full.

Comment: sorry about that, i've edited my question.

Comment: You can use some curve fitting for some values that are close to your example. f(x)≈f(x)≈−1.02954*x*x+377.192*x−194.527. Might not be your 100% the same but it comes close. If you use a more fitting curve fitting compared to a simple square function, you can get closer values but the formula won't fit into a comment

Comment: yeah! i agree that the equation seems to follow a quadratic function. I will follow your steps, thanks!